# How can I type an Object coming from a .forEach function?

Tags: typescript

I have this array or ITest objects:

```
var x: ITest[] = 

[{"adminTestId":131,"code":"abcde","userTestId":1},
 {"adminTestId":130,"code":"ddddd","userTestId":2}]
```

I created a function that I could use to get an object out of this given the userTestId:

```
elem = (arr, property, num) => {
    arr.forEach(function (elem, index) {
        if (elem[property] === num)
            return elem;
    })
};
```

When I call it like this I get an error:

```
var test: ITest = <ITest> this.elem(this.tests, 'userTestId', userTestId);

Error   5   Cannot convert 'void' to 'ITest'.
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong. I want to type the output of this.elem to be of type ITest in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here: you can't short circuit a forEach and the elem var within the forEach is not assessable outside of the loop.

One solution is the following:

```
        elem = (arr : any[], property, num) => {
        var found = null;
        arr.forEach(function (elem, index) {
            if (elem[property] === num) {
                found = elem;
            }
        })

        return found;
    };
```

You could shorten that to:

```
        var foundItems = arr.filter((item) => item[property] === num);
        return foundItems.length === 1 ? foundItems[0] : null;
```

Or alternatively you could use something like lodash:

```
_.find(arr, (item) => item[property] === num);
```